# Google Cloud - OneTap - Issue - Anyone without an account can login

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Under API & Services, user type is External

Under Test Users, I have added users, however on testing anyone even if not on the test users list can log in successfully. Why is this so? And how can I locked this down for testing purposes

Thank You

(Your app will only be available to users you add to the list of test
users)

```
                        <div id="g_id_onload"
                            data-client_id="MyClientID"
                            data-context="signin" data-ux_mode="redirect"
                            data-login_uri="https://mywebsite.com"
                            data-auto_select="true">
                        </div>

                        <div id="menuStyle">
                            <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="rectangular" data-theme="outline"
                                data-text="signin_with" data-size="large" data-locale="en" data-logo_alignment="left">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```